# For each $p \in \mathbb{R}$ I need to find the values of $x$ for which the series converges

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}x^n \mbox{ }(x,p \in \mathbb{R}), (n \in \mathbb{N})$$

For each value of $p$, I need to find the values of $x$ for which the series converges. It looks like a power series where $x_0 = 0$. So I can compute that the radius of convergence is $R = 1$

But now what? I understand that the convergence range is $[-1, 1]$ for every $p > 1$, but what about other values of $p$?

Am I even doing it right or am I wrong all the way?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea - but check the $p$ values again. You say for every $p > 1$ there is convergence (so long as $|x| < 1$), but I think this is true for more than just $p > 1$.

The boundary cases where $x = \pm 1$ can be handled separately (recall the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), which may come in handy here).